# Why does casting and dereferencing struct pointers lose information?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, casting

I have two struct types

```
typedef struct {
    int i;
    int j;
} struct_a;

typedef struct {
    int i;
} struct_b;
```

where `struct_a` and `struct_b` obviously share a common initial sequence. Based on these structs I have the following snippet in which I convert between `struct_a` and `struct_b` by casting and dereferencing pointers

```
struct_a a = { 0, 1 };
printf("%i %i\n", a.i, a.j);

struct_b b = *((struct_b *)&a);
printf("%i\n", b.i);

struct_a c = *((struct_a *)&b);
printf("%i %i\n", c.i, c.j);
```

The output of the above code after compiling with gcc is

```
0 1
0
0 0 <= ?
```

My question is why does `c` lose the value of `j` that was specified when initializing `a`? Is it because dereferencing the pointers, for instance, in

```
struct_b b = *((struct_b *)&a);
```

effectively copies the struct?

Comment: Because you're copying the dereference of the pointer. You aren't storing the pointer.

Comment: Yes; `a` and `b` occupy separate addresses. In dereferencing `(struct_b *)&a`, you're only copying `sizeof(struct_b)` bytes into `b` and the rest is lost.

Comment: "where struct_b obviously is a subtype of struct_a" – no, conversely.

Comment: "obviously is a subtype". Obviously C doesn't have subtypes, but if you are going to apply this notion to C, then it's the other way around: struct_a is a subtype of struct_b.

Comment: By casting one `struct` pointer to the type of another and then de-referencing it, you're breaking C's "strict aliasing rules" (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) and the behavior is undefined.  After that point, pretty much anything goes including the apparent "information loss" that you've observed; although you've also copied from a `struct_b` to a `struct_a` object, which is where the loss really comes from in this case. The assignment to `struct_b b` only assigns the fields of `struct_b`, naturally enough.

Comment: @davmac here strict aliasing is not violated because a and b share a common initial sequence. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846551/structures-and-casting-in-c).

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant the "common initial sequence" clause is for access to structs as members of a _union_. It is not a general license to assume that structs with a common initial sequence may partially alias.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant (and anyway, the "common initial sequence" clause only allows access to that initial sequence. The code in question access a `struct_b` object via a `struct_a` pointer and tries to read the whole `struct_a` object, thus exceeding the initial sequence).

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant / @n.m.: Sorry I meant `struct_b` is a subset of `struct_a` in the sense that they have the same initial sequence. Subtype is obviously the wrong word here. Thanks for catching that sloppiness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are copying. When copying `a` to `b`, there is only room for one value. The other one is lost.

And the cast in the last assignment is not allowed, so you could have *any* result from that.

Comment: The _cast_ in the last assignment is certainly allowed. De-referencing the result of it is not.

Comment: @davmac it is, again, since `struct_b` and `struct_a` have a common initial sequence (namely, an `int`).

Comment: (which makes both this answer and the comment wrong. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846551/structures-and-casting-in-c)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant see my similar response above. Further, I do not believe the accepted answer to the question that you link to is correct; I have commented on it to explain why (and given some code that shows that at least two compilers agree with my interpretation).

Comment: @davmac I'll look at your comment in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

#### Casting and dereferencing struct pointers does not lose information.

Some notes about your code:

- `a`, `b` and `c` are different locations in memory.
- `c.j` has not been initialized in the code, its value could be anything.

Casting the type back and forth for the **same** variable produces the expected result:

```
struct_a c = *((struct_a *)((struct_b *)&a)); 
printf("%i %i\n", c.i, c.j);
```

Another option that produces the expected result:

```
struct_a a = { 0, 1 };
printf("%i %i\n", a.i, a.j);

struct_b *b = (struct_b *)&a; // *b points a
printf("%i\n", b->i);

struct_a c = *((struct_a *)b); // c is a copy of a
printf("%i %i\n", c.i, c.j);
```

Comment: `c` sure as heck is not at the same location as `b`. It is a different object.